# Error in My SQL Syntax for trigger creation or execution

Tags: mysql, sql, database, triggers

#### value_table

- id auto increment not null unique
- primary_object_id
- user_id
- value

#### group_table

- id auto increment not null unique
- primary_object_id
- 1
- 2
- 3
- 4
- 5
- 6
- 7

I have two tables one stores values(value_table) and other(group_value) stores values count. There are about 7 numeric columns in group_table 1 to 7.

Each user can give a value between 1 to 7 to the object who has id=primary_object_id and can also update the same, So I need to keep track how many users have given 1 to different objects with their respective primary_object_id

Now what I am trying to achieve is if their is update on value_table say initially 4 to final 7 then I want to update group_value table and increment count of column with name 7 by 1, and decrement count of column with name 4

I have came to this SQL but it gives syntax error

I know there is the error only in those two consecutive statements, because I tried static update statement like

```
update group_value set `7` = `7` + 1 where id=OLD.primary_object_id;;
```

The above statement works. But How I could I use the old values and new values to update value in group_value table

```
DELIMITER |

  CREATE TRIGGER UpdateCount AFTER UPDATE ON value_table FOR EACH ROW 

  BEGIN
      IF OLD.value <> NEW.value THEN
        UPDATE group_value SET `OLD.value` = `OLD.value` - 1 where id=OLD.primary_object_id;
        UPDATE group_value SET `NEW.value` = `NEW.value` + 1 where id=OLD.primary_object_id;
      END IF;
  END;
|
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Please add the table definitions in full.and sample data

Comment: id in value_table cannot be primary key since the auto_increment column id must be the primary key.. please add the output of show create table <tablename> for both tables

Comment: ok, just updating in a couple of minutes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Table alias and column alias must be quoted separately.

Not

```
UPDATE group_value SET `OLD.value` = `OLD.value` - 1 where id=OLD.id;
```

but

```
UPDATE group_value SET `OLD`.`value` = `OLD`.`value` - 1 where id=OLD.id;
```

---

> if user updates his value in value_table from 4 to 5 then I need to reduce count of 4 by 1 and increment count of 5 by 1 in group_value tab

The task is to use the column's value as the name of the column? This needs in prepared statement but it is not allowed in triggers.

The only solution may be:

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER UpdateCount 
AFTER UPDATE 
ON value_table 
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
    CASE OLD.value 
        WHEN 1 
        THEN UPDATE group_value SET `1` = `1` - 1 WHERE id=OLD.primary_object_id;
        WHEN 2 
        THEN UPDATE group_value SET `2` = `2` - 1 WHERE id=OLD.primary_object_id;
        WHEN 3 
        THEN UPDATE group_value SET `3` = `3` - 1 WHERE id=OLD.primary_object_id;
        WHEN 4 
        THEN UPDATE group_value SET `4` = `4` - 1 WHERE id=OLD.primary_object_id;
        WHEN 5 
        THEN UPDATE group_value SET `5` = `5` - 1 WHERE id=OLD.primary_object_id;
        WHEN 6 
        THEN UPDATE group_value SET `6` = `6` - 1 WHERE id=OLD.primary_object_id;
        WHEN 7 
        THEN UPDATE group_value SET `7` = `7` - 1 WHERE id=OLD.primary_object_id;
    END CASE;
    CASE NEW.value 
        WHEN 1 
        THEN UPDATE group_value SET `1` = `1` + 1 WHERE id=NEW.primary_object_id;
        WHEN 2 
        THEN UPDATE group_value SET `2` = `2` + 1 WHERE id=NEW.primary_object_id;
        WHEN 3 
        THEN UPDATE group_value SET `3` = `3` + 1 WHERE id=NEW.primary_object_id;
        WHEN 4 
        THEN UPDATE group_value SET `4` = `4` + 1 WHERE id=NEW.primary_object_id;
        WHEN 5 
        THEN UPDATE group_value SET `5` = `5` + 1 WHERE id=NEW.primary_object_id;
        WHEN 6 
        THEN UPDATE group_value SET `6` = `6` + 1 WHERE id=NEW.primary_object_id;
        WHEN 7 
        THEN UPDATE group_value SET `7` = `7` + 1 WHERE id=NEW.primary_object_id;
    END CASE;
END
```

But I strongly recommend to normalize the data.

Comment: Sorry but this isn't working and shouldn't work because OLD is not table alias, its a trigger variable that comes with update trigger

Comment: I know what is OLD alias. And I cannot find the reason to quote it at all - but you may if you want. Moreover, I cannot understand the logic of your trigger at all - what's the reason to assign `OLD.value`? it will be dropped anyway... And why this is performed in UPDATE and not using SET?

Comment: I enquoted OLD what I tried but don't know how should I embed basically old value for column name, basically I am storing counts for e.g if user updates his value in value_table from 4 to 5 then I need to reduce count of 4 by 1 and increment count of 5 by 1 in group_value table

Comment: @NimishBansal o_O Do you want to use column's value as the name of the column to be altered?

Comment: Thanks a lot. Can I just ask will it be a little slower? or negligible

Comment: @NimishBansal *will it be a little slower?* This won't be slower than 2 separate updates for definite columns without CASE. But it will be slower than one update for two definite columns with high probability.

Comment: and sir one last question how could I normalize it? If I can't run group concat always for each user

Comment: @NimishBansal `CREATE TABLE group_table (id AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, primary_object_id INT, group_number TINYINT, group_value INT);` where `group_number` is a number from 1 to 7 and `group_value` is according value/amount for this object and group.

Comment: Ok, so basically instead of storing horizontally I should store it vertically in form of tuples. Thanks a lot for all your suggestions sir

Comment: @NimishBansal Additionally - I do not see the reason in synthetic primary key whereas you have excellent natural one: `CREATE TABLE group_table (primary_object_id INT, group_number TINYINT, group_value INT, PRIMARY KEY (primary_object_id, group_number));`. This PK will be clustered and hence it does not need in additional disk space.